# Any way to have 2 concentration spells active?

Tags: dnd-5e, concentration, caster-level

Is there any spell, item, or skill that allows a caster to maintain 2 concentration spells active at same time?

Comment: @Overthinks [please don’t answer in comments](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6533/14878).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## No

That would be unbalancing and run contrary to the entire reason for concentration spells. There are a number of ways to partially work around this limitation:

1. Rings of spell storing and ioun stones of reserve can hold spells in them for later casting. Acquire one for an ally and cast a concentration spell into the item. Your ally will be handling the concentration when they activate the spell.
2. As above, but give the magical item to your familiar.
3. Sorcerers can use the twin spell metamagic to cast certain concentration spells on two targets instead of one.

Comment: Unfortunately, site rules forbid answering the question before the user has tagged the question with the correct game edition, even if it's clear from the question.

Comment: edition 5e, sorry ^^"